# Why the property is not setting in Salesforce Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a VisualForce page **testPage**

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    {!myString}, {!myString1}, {!myString2}, {!Mystring3}, {!myString}
</apex:page>
```

And the controller is

```
public class testController {
    public string myString {get;set;}
    public string getMyString1()
    {
        return myString;
    }

    public string getMyString2()
    {
        if(myString==null)
            myString = 'Method2';
        return myString;
    }

    public void getMystring3()
    {
        myString = 'Method3';
    }
}
```

When loading the page, it outputs `, , Method2, ,`.
The methods **getMyString2** and **getMystring3** both set the property.
Why the `myString` property is not set here?

Comment: Have you tried using simple setString() method? instead of set; and get;

Answer (score 0):

I know Salesforce used to reserve the word "test" for test classes. If it's not firing at all, try renaming it. Salesforce may thing they're test classes.

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating the merge expressions in the page:

```
{!myString}, {!myString1}, {!myString2}, {!Mystring3}, {!myString}
```

The order of events is:

1., `testController get(myString)`, which is null, since the variable hasn't been initialized

2., `testController get(myString1)`, which is also null since the value being returned is still null

3., `testController get(myString2)`, which sets the variable `myString` to the value of `Method2` and returns that value

4., `testController get(Mystring3)`, which returns sets the variable `myString` to the value `Method3` and returns nothing

5., That's it. Even though `{!myString}` is written again in the visualforce page, the page doesn't go back to the controller to get the value again, since it already got it once and already knows it's value; assuming (mistakenly in this case) that the value hadn't changed.

---

If you changed your VF page to:

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
    {!myString1}, {!myString2}, {!Mystring3}, {!myString}
</apex:page>
```

`testController get(myString)` would be called after `testController get(Mystring3)`, so the resulting page would display:

> , Method2, , Method3

---

All that being said, a getter shouldn't change the state of a program, and if you are relying on this type of behavior, it will only make your code hard to understand.